# Add to DateInterval a previously given \DateTime + days

Tags: symfony, datetime, addition

I need to persist in `next_payment_date` property the value of `starts_at`, added to the value of the `check_for`, that can be either `30` or `60`. In other words, if my `start_date` is 2015-10-30, I need to add 30 or 60 days to it and set to the `next_payment_date`.

It is a PreUpdate method that is executed when my Budget entity is persisted into the database:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onPre()
{
    $this->getBudget()->setNextPaymentDate($this->generateNextPaymentDate());
}
```

The first attempt to set my `next_payment_date`:

```
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    $startsAt = $this->getBudget()->getStartsAt();

    if ($startsAt !== null) {
        return $startsAt->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getBudget()->getCheckFor() . 'D'));
    }
}
```

Then, I had another idea. Since the date is primarily NULL, I added the `starts_at` value to it before, then modified:

```
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    $this->getBudget()->setNextPaymentDate($this->getBudget()->getStartsAt());

    return $this->getBudget()->getNextPaymentDate()->modify('+' . $this->getBudget()->getCheckFor() . ' day');
}
```

But somehow the same result was given. The `starts_at` property was being updated along with `next_payment_date`, both of them had the same value. How do I update only the `next_payment_date`?

Comment: Hi what is the value of $this->getBudget()->getCheckFor() can you check for that

Comment: @AshishAwasthi It is either 30 or 60.

Answer (score 0):

If `$startsAt` is a `Datetime` object:

```
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    const NEXT_DATE = '+30days';

    $startsAt = $this->getBudget()->getStartsAt();

    if ($startsAt !== null) {
         return $startsAt->modify(self::NEXT_DATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems it will modify the own `starts_at`. I need to grab its value and add 30 or 60 to `next_payment_date`, without modifying the `starts__at`, get it? If `starts_at` is 2015-10-30, I need `next_payment_date` to be 2015-11-29.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

```
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    $date = new \DateTime($this->getBudget()->getStartsAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
    return $date->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getBudget()->getCheckFor(). 'D'));
}
```